# How do i break out of a loop when the user types in a specific string?

Tags: java, string, while-loop, queue

I am trying to create two queues. One queue that holds a list of male names. And another queue holding a list of female names. The user has to type in a gender type before the name. So the program is supposed to know which queue the name goes into by an "m" or an "f". When I am typing in "m bob" or "f jill" and hit enter. It prints out the statement twice. Also when i type in "x done" it doesnt break out and print out the two lists.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UsesArrayBndQueue {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayUnbndQueue<String> test = new ArrayUnbndQueue<String>();
    ArrayUnbndQueue<String> test2 = new ArrayUnbndQueue<String>();
    boolean NotFull = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   while(true)
    {
      System.out.println("Input a gender and a name (x done to quit):");
     String str1 = scan.next();
      if(str1.contains("x done")){
          break;
      }
     else if(str1.contains("m")){
         test.enqueue(str1);
      }
      else if(str1.contains("f")){
          test2.enqueue(str1);
      }
   }

  while (!test.isEmpty())
    {
      try
      {
        String str1 = test.dequeue();
        System.out.println(str1);
        String str2 = test2.dequeue();
        System.out.println(str2);

      }
      catch(QueueUnderflowException Except)
      {
        System.out.println(Except.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Set the loops exit condition to whatever you want to be...instead of `while(true)`, you might also want to consider using a `do-while` loop instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan.next()` doesn't take space so str1 will never be "x done"

As an alternative you can do this

```
 while(true)
    {
      System.out.println("Input a gender and a name (x_done to quit):");
     String str1 = scan.next();
      if(str1.equals("x_done")){
          break;
      }
     else if(str1.equals("m")){
         test.enqueue(scan.next());
      }
      else if(str1.equals("f")){
          test2.enqueue(scan.next());
      }
   }
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why when i type in x done it doesnt print out the two queues? It just terminates

Comment: @user3541085 how does the while loop break? scan.next() will ignore all your spaces and new lines. I have to see your code to know what is happening.

Comment: I cant figure out how to show the code in the comments

Comment: 'while(true){
       System.out.println("Input a gender and a name (x done to quit):");
       str1 = scan.nextLine();
       if(str1.equals("x done")){
        break;
       }
      else if(str1.equals("m")){
       test.enqueue(scan.nextLine());
       }
       else if(str1.equals("f")){
        test2.enqueue(scan.nextLine());
       }
    }'

Comment: @user3541085 if you are using nextLine(), then you should change from equals to startsWith or indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

Set the exit condition of your loop to whatever you need to exit the loop.

In your case, you may want to use a `do-while` loop, as you need to loop at least once...

```
boolean keepAsking = true;
do {
    keepAsking = false;
    System.out.println("Input a gender and a name (x done to quit):");
    String str1 = scan.nextLine();
    if(str1.contains("x done")){
    }
    else if(str1.contains("m")){
         test.enqueue(str1);
    }
    else if(str1.contains("f")){
        test2.enqueue(str1);
    } else {
        keepAsking = true;
    }
} while (keepAsking);
```

You should also be using `Scanner#nextLine`, otherwise you will only get the next whole word (delimited by the space)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from The solution provided.. make sure you compare it using Case conversion or equalsIgnoreCase for proper work of logic..